# How to open jupyter in WSL via terminal with a specific starting directory?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, alias, anaconda, jupyter

I unfortunately didn't found a solution to the above described problem. 
Since there are several python packages only available for linux I want to use python now from WSL.
I installed anaconda on windows 10 subsystem linux and open the jupyter notebook via the self def.

```
 alias jnb='cd ~/anaconda3/share && jupyter notebook --allow-root --no-browser'
```

this gives me a path which i can copy into a browser and opens jupyter notebook.
The problem is how to get from this starting dir to my windows file system.
If i open the jupyter e.g in

```
`'cd /mnt/c/Users/maths/Documents/University/Dissatation`
```

this is not the starting dir from the jupyter nb (as it is if I do the same in cmd).

I am glad to hear any suggestion. 
It would be also nice if someone knows how to directly open a notebook in a specific browser (e.g. chrome) from ubuntu terminal on win 10., because just omitting  --no-browser does not work
merci
BR
maths

Comment: I tried it. It works as you expected in latest Windows 10 version.

Comment: hmmm strange it does not work in my case. It completely ignores the actual directory. Can you show me your way/alias for opening jupyter?

Comment: Just `cd /mnt/c/folder` and `jupyter notebook`, simple!

Comment: Thats not working in my case! It is giving: JupyterLab application directory is /root/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab ..... it suggest to use --allow-root to bypass, but this always gives the same starting dir. ->~ .... (there is no escape from there).. maybe I shouldn't have installed anaconda on root (but I didn't managed it for another dir)